# Can Magento import products by cron job?

Tags: magento2, import, cron

I know Magento provide us to create our custom cron job. Is it possible to create a cron job that imports the products?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can create cron based module that will be run on specified time based on cron. In module, you can write piece of code that will read `CSV` file and import product in system. So it is based on programming.